# How to disable other validations in case more important validation error is caught

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, error-handling

I want a (numerical) model attribute `foo` to be validated as

- (1) present, and
- (2) be greater than or equal to 0.

Since (1) is a prerequisite to (2), in case no value is given for parameter `foo`, I want the validation to report only the error related to (1), and not (2).

I tried to do it like this:

```
validates :foo_attribute,
  numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0},
  presence: true
```

But when the given value of parameter `:foo` is absent, I get messages in `errors` that originate from both validations (1) and (2).

In such case, how can I get only the validation error related to (1) and not (2)?

Comment: Is it not an option to use 2 separate validation lines for presence and numericality ?

Comment: @sajan That would make it even worse.

Comment: I think you need to write your own validation method

Comment: @sawa I was implying something like this `validates :foo_attribute,
  numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}, if: 'foo_attribute.present?'`

Comment: @sajan I see. That will work. But if that is the way I should go, then I wonder what the purpose was for the `validates :foo_attribute, numericality: {greater_than_or_qaeusl_to: 0}, presence: true` syntax (which is elegant but does not work). It seems useless.

Comment: @sawa I can't say for others but for me, this kind of syntax is only useless when one validation is dependent on other, like in your case. otherwise it is helpful. for ex. this `validates :foo_attribute, uniqueness: true, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}, length: { is: 3 }, if: 'foo_attribute.present?'` . In this case we are applying 3 validation, if the attribute is present and since all had a dependency on presence: true, it can be easily combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like internally validates() just splits it into multiple validations:

```
def validates(*attributes)
  defaults = attributes.extract_options!.dup
  validations = defaults.slice!(*_validates_default_keys)

  raise ArgumentError, "You need to supply at least one attribute" if attributes.empty?
  raise ArgumentError, "You need to supply at least one validation" if validations.empty?

  defaults[:attributes] = attributes

  validations.each do |key, options|
    next unless options
    key = "#{key.to_s.camelize}Validator"

    begin
      validator = key.include?('::') ? key.constantize : const_get(key)
    rescue NameError
      raise ArgumentError, "Unknown validator: '#{key}'"
    end

    validates_with(validator, defaults.merge(_parse_validates_options(options)))
  end
end
```

That being the case, you would have to either write your own method or do something like:

```
validates_presence_of :foo_attribute
validates_numericality_of :foo_attribute, greater_than: 0, unless: Proc.new { |foo_instance| foo_instance.foo_attribute.nil? }
```